# How do I create an instance of a parameterized interface

Tags: java, generics

I have this code:

```
ObjProcessor processor = getProcessor();
MyClass myObj = getObjToProcess();// MyClass extends PersistentObj
```

and classes:

```
public class ObjProcessor {
   public <OP extends PersistentObj) void process(Class<OP> objClazz, OP object, Modifier<OP> modifier) {
     ...
   }
}
public interface Modifier<T> {
    void modify(T obj);
}
```

I am stuck. How do I create an instance of the Modifier to be able to invoke:

```
processor.process(myObj.getClass(), myObj, ???);
```

---

After Ron C's comment, I created this Modifier:

```
 Modifier<MyClass> mod = new Modifier<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public void modify(MyClass obj) {
       // empty
    }
}; 

proc.process(myObj.getClass(), myObj, mod); // compilation error!
```

Eclipse gave this error:

```
The method process(Class<OP>, OP, Modifier<OP>) in the type ObjProcessor is not applicable for the arguments (Class< capture#1-of ? extends MyClass>, MyClass, Modifier<MyClass>)
```

Comment: You need to write a class that implements `Modifier<T>`. It could be anonymous.

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **anonymous inner class** as an instance of the `Modifier` interface:

```
processor.process(myObj.getClass(), myObj, new Modifier<MyClass>() {

    @Override
    public void modify(MyClass obj) {
        //Add implementation here
    }
});
```

If you're using `java 8`, you can also use [lambada expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Because your `interface` is considered as a **Functional Interface** (interface with only one method), you can use lambada expression instead of creating anonymous class:

```
processor.process(myObj.getClass(), myObj, obj -> {
    //Add implementation here
});
```

---

For the second problem, the solution is to change the declaration of process to:

```
public <OP extends ObjProcessor> void process(Class<? extends OP> objClazz, OP object, Modifier<OP> modifier) {

}
```

I've replaced `Class<OP>` with `Class<? extends OP>`. The older decleration only works with: `MyClass.class`, but not with: `instanceOfMyClass.getClass()`.

The reason for this is that the `Class<OP>` type argument can't accept `Class<ClassExtendsOP>` as an argument, it's only allow one class.

If your'e using `MyClass` as `OP`,
when you're using `MyClass.class`, you're always getting `Class<MyClass>` object. But when you're using `instanceOfMyClass.getClass()`, you can get `Class<ClassExtendsMyClass>`, which not match the argument type.

Comment: Thanks Ron but did not solve it. See my addition after I tried your solution.

Comment: I cannot modify ObjProcessor since it's a third party library.

Comment: Then you must use `MyClass.class` as an argument. I'm about to explain whay.

Comment: thanks Ron. Got it. Will try later.